# Is it possible to random generate tmx (map) files in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Basically, I'm making an iPhone RPG as a little project for myself, I'm using Cocos2d and thus 2D tiled maps. I had planned to do randomly generate the levels for the map, but have realised it may be harder than I think to randomly generate them and keep collidable tiles working.

Is this possible to do, and has anyone done it?

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. Just generate random coordinates to assign to `UIMapView`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with tmx file format you are asking about but usually the way you go about generating a map is to start with the physics of the map not the visual representation. Here is two way to do it

(1) Define materials (water, sand, rock)

(2) Define how much of each you want to use in the map (as percentage)

(3) Place material seeds in your map

(4) Grow the seeds by expanding the material in all directions until the space is full

(5) Now define relation between visual tile and material. If it's transition from one material to another or 100% of one material.

(6) Generate your visual representation using material map and relation between materials and art.

...

(3) Fill your map with the materials you defined using the appropriate amount you defined.

(4) Use clustarization algorithm to swap tiles and form islands. (increasing the number of steps of your clustarization algorithm will make fewer but larger islands)

...

(0) There may be some other rules that the map needs to follow like accesability from one area to another. You can start by placing that in your physics map first and not allowing the other algorithms to break it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative answer. I'm ashamed to admit that I neglected to inform you all in my question that I'm using Cocos2d to make a 2D game, and thus desire a randomly generated 2D tiled map.

Comment: You can also apply these principles to tmx-files in 2D. Cocos2D does not have methods to create new random maps. You need to build them.

Answer (score 0):

Random map generation is possible and is used in many games. Diablo is one of the first games that come to my mind. Don't forget to set proper boundaries for the generation algorithm, however, because it might create a map with impassable locations.